# How can I get the events of 2 radionbuttons on 2 groupboxs in C#?

Tags: c#, events, groupbox

Form1 has 2 groupboxs:

- groupbox1: radiobutton1 and radiobutton2
- groupbox2: radiobutton3 and radiobutton4

Code here:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    radioButton1.Checked = true; //create a default selection
    radioButton3.Checked = true; //create a default selection
}
```

Events here:

```
private void radioButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("radioButton1_Click");
}

private void radioButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("radioButton3_Click");
}
```

When the program runs, why do the `radioButton1_Click` event call only?
How to call both `radioButton1_Click` and `radioButton3_Click`?

Comment: is the event set up? just the presence of the radioButton3_Click() doesn't actually make the event work ... at some place, usually the designer code, there needs to be a line of code that registers the eventhandler ... if you do this with visual studio, check the event properties of RadioButton1 and RadioButton3

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to use the `Click` event instead of the `CheckedChanged` event?